# munched his way through the chocolate

Tags: subjects

> (1)
>   It was a nice feeling, sitting there with Ron, eating **their way** through all Harry's pasties, cakes, and candies (the sandwiches lay forgotten). 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone, by J. K. Rowling)
>
> (2)
>       He bought himself a family-sized bar of Dairy Milk on the way to Malet Street. Bernie Coleman, an acquaintance in the Army Medical Corps, had once explained to Strike how the majority of the symptoms associated with a crashing hangover were due to dehydration and hypoglycemia, which were the inevitable results of prolonged vomiting. Strike munched **his way** through the chocolate, crutches jammed under his arm and every step jarring his head, which still felt as though it was being compressed by tight wires. (The Cuckoo’s calling, by Robert Galbraith)

It seems that *(2)’s way* is as the same eating way as *(1)*. But the next phrases confuse me, that are *crutches jammed under his arm and every step jarring his head*. This ‘*Munched his way through the chocolate*’ would be a finished or an ongoing activity. Then what are the subjects for the aforementioned phrase: *Strike*, or *crutches; step*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence could be rephrased as:

> Strike munched his way through the chocolate, [while he walked with] crutches jammed under his arm and every step jarring his head, [and his head] still felt as though it was being compressed by tight wires."

So "munched his way through the chocolate" is an ongoing activity while he walks with crutches.  Strike is the subject of "[walked with] crutches...".  Strike's head is the subject of "still felt...".